# After upgrade from 20.04 to 21.04 many applications won't start

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I updated from 20.04 to 21.04. The installation completed successfully and rebooting works. But if I start Firefox or Writer or Chromium, the hours glass appears, but no window ever opens.

I've tried reinstalling firefox

$ sudo apt install --reinstall firefox

But that didn't make any difference. I tried loggin it with "Ubuntu xorg", but that didn't matter, either.

Comment: When release upgrades fail the best and faster solution is a fresh installation.

Comment: You must have upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10, then to 21.04? Please describe, because an upgrade of 20.04 directly to 21.04 is supported. Can you open a terminal? If yes, then launch firefox from the command line. That may reveal error messages. But I agree with ChanganAuto that a fresh install may be the shortest pain.

Answer (score 0):

If the application shows on the dock, click on it, try pressing Alt-Space and see if you can Maximize it or Move it back on to your screen.  Worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I finally just reinstalled 21.04 from scratch erasing the prior upgrade from 20.10 in the process. Everything works fine now.